# SQL Server query talking longer with union and a column with view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Using a SQL Server database, I have some SQL code which tries to fetch from a couple of tables with union and is working fine.

New requirement is to add a column to the existing SQL statements which reads from a view. I ran the individual SQL statements, they are running fine after adding the new column as well talking little longer than the original ones.

Now trying to run all the SQL statements together with the union and it's running forever.

```
select 
    col 1, col 2, col3, 
    case 
       when 'ee' = (select col 5 from view1 where X.id = id) 
          then 'xx'  
          else 'yy' 
    end as newcol1
from
    X, Y, Z
where 
    condn 1 and condn 2

union

select 
    col 1, col 2, col3, 
    case 
       when 'ee' = (select col 5 from view1 where X.id = id) 
          then 'xx' 
          else 'yy' 
    end as newcol1 
from 
    X, Y, Z
where 
    condn 3 and condn 4

union

select 
    col 1, col 2, col3, 
    case 
       when 'ee' = (select col 5 from view1 where X.id = id) 
          then 'xx' 
          else 'yy' 
    end as newcol1 
from 
    X, Y, Z
where 
    condn 5 and condn 6
```

Any suggestions for optimizing this query?

Comment: That's not a query... That's pseudo-code...  "from X, Y, Z" is ansii 89 syntax for a 3 way Cartesian product. That, by itself, should perform horribly. On top of that, the correlated sub-query "(SELECT Col 5 from view1..." is going to execute once for every row in the outer query... And then... you're doing it 3 times... And the cherry on top is the fact that you're using UNIONs rather that UNION ALL, meaning that you've added a distinct operation into the mix. You may have a perfect storm here.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks, for responses. Will change the from to use joins. How can I change the newcol1 to??? to perform better. Using the above I am able to get the result what I need but it's performance is bad. Please provide an example as vladatr.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that a lot of people overlook is that `UNION` will not just return the union of all the rows of the subqueries, but it will check for duplicates, so it could slow the query a lot. If you want to return all the results of the three subqueries including duplicates you should use `UNION ALL` which usually is much faster.

For example, suppose that you get these results from the individual subqueries:

```
Query 1   Query 2   Query 3
-------   -------   -------
1, 1, 1   1, 1, 1   4, 5, 6
2, 2, 2   3, 3, 3   7, 8, 9
1, 2, 3   3, 2, 1   1, 2, 3
3, 2, 1             3, 2, 1
```

using `UNION` you will get:

```
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2
1, 2, 3
3, 2, 1
3, 3, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

and using `UNION ALL` you will get:

```
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2
1, 2, 3
3, 2, 1
1, 1, 1
3, 3, 3
3, 2, 1
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
1, 2, 3
3, 2, 1
```

If you really need the query returns only the distinct rows from the three subqueries, you maybe need to add indexes on the columns returned by the query, maybe they current query is relying on automatic indexes created by SQL Server and the changes made the optimizer stop using them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to rewrite the whole query:

```
SELECT col 1, col 2, col3, 
    case 
       when v.col5 = 'ee'
          then 'xx'  
          else 'yy' end as newcol1
FROM X
INNER JOIN Y ON Y.??? = X.???
INNER JOIN Z ON Z.??? = X.???
LEFT OUTER JOIN view1 v ON v.id = X.id AND col5 = 'ee' 
WHERE (condn 1 and condn 2)
   OR (condn 3 and condn 3)
   OR (condn 5 and condn 6)
```

This way the table X,Y,Z need to be read only once.